# SVG being cut off while rendering on website screen with overflow

Tags: css, svg, viewbox, animejs

I'm trying to make a parallax effect train animation for a personal project. This was done by translating the background svgs (`translateX`) at different speeds. I have achieved this using `animejs` library. However, during animation the SVG gets cut off in between as shown below.

I have tried the following things before to resolve the issue

- `overflow : visible`
- Fiddling with the view box of the SVG

*both of them didn't work*

Not sure if it's an issue with SVG or the CSS used to render it on the website

[image: SVG being cut during animation]

Here is the codesandbox link
[Codesandbox Train Animation](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-svg-4td8j)

Comment: that might be because of clip path you have in your svg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Salil Rajkarnikar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14475618/salil-rajkarnikar), just removed the clip-path property in the svg and it worked.